# jVectorMap height:% does not work

Tags: javascript, css, jvectormap

I am using this library: http://jvectormap.com/ to create a Map for my website. I am attempting to set the width and height of the map to 100% through the style attribute to make the map display at full-screen size.

When I specify the following:

```
<div id="map1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></div>
```

The map displays as follows:
[image]

The width attribute appears to work correctly, however the height attribute does not. When I resize the window, the width scales correctly, whereas the height appears to scale up constantly regardless of whether I scale the image up or down.

How can I make the map appear with a specified scale using a percentage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your CSS:

```
head {
    height:100%;
}
#map1 {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
}
```

Setting the height of the head element to 100% sets the definition for what the map height will be.

Comment: You are a God! Thank you so much. I have spent hours on this issue. I will set it as the correct answer asap.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try using vh instead of %

```
<div id="map1" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to jVectorMap to take full height and width, then add outer **div** container to the map. Also set width and height Outer  container.

```
<div class="map-container">
     <div id="world-map" class="jvmap-smart"></div>
</div>
```

Next add css styles.

```
.map-container{
    height: 300px;
}

.jvmap-smart{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;  
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 576px) {
    .map-container{
        height: 350px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .map-container{
        height: 400px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    .map-container{
        height: 500px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .map-container{
        height: 600px;
    }
}
```

To know more about jVectorMap refer this link https://smarttutorials.net/how-to-create-make-responsive-world-map-jvectormap-using-jquery/

Answer (score -1):

If you simply want the map to be shown correctly at any size on initial load, you can use :

```
<div id="map1" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
```